# Using Python to Populate MS Access Form

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

How would I use Python to populate a MS Access form field. The following query provides records showing the `completion_metric` as a percent for each `short_ID`.

My next goal is use Python to populate a field with the value of a `completion_metric` once the subject id is entered into the form. So I want Python to show the value of the `completion_metric` on the MS Access form when the subject id is typed onto the form. How would I go about doing this?

So far I have managed to fetch all the records from my query, my last task is to now populate my form once Python is triggered.
The following is my select query the I would be using to get the value of the completion metric.

```sql
SELECT Short_ID, FORMAT(SUM( IIF (Status = 'Completed',  1 , 0)) /  COUNT (Status), 'percent' ) AS completion_metric
FROM PROMIS_LT_Long_ID
GROUP BY Short_ID;
```

Comment: I am confused why you need Python: *my last task is to now populate my form once Python is triggered*. Why can't you handle all form needs in MS Access? Can't you set the record source of form to that query?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the form field is connected to a database table field. The database will be updated, as it is the setup in ms access, as soon as the form field is changed. So you could read the data directly from the database. The tricky part here might be to know when the form field has changed. Therefor more information about your python would be needed.